# Can Django Paginator start with last page and page backwards?

Tags: django, pagination, django-views

I'm creating a messaging feature using Django.  I'd like to implement the page that shows all messages between two users with Django's [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/pagination/) feature.  What I'm trying to do is if the number of messages exceeds the paginator's "per_page" count, I'd want Django to display the object list starting with the ***last*** page, not the first.  If this occurs, I'd also like to display a link at the top of the page that says "See older messages" which, when clicked, would show the next-to-last group of messages in the object list, etc.  In essence, the user should be able to page through their messages starting at the end and viewing their newest messages first and then work their way back to look at older messages.  Is it possible to have Django's paginator start displaying messages at the end of the object list?  I've read the Paginator document but I don't see a way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: curious; why not simply order the messages newest, to oldest; so that the first page have the newest, then to see older you move "down" the pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the number of pages in paginator and set the current page to the last page num:

```
page = request.GET('page')
if not page:
    page = paginator.num_pages
```